# Swap two objects of class

Tags: c++

my class has some private and public elements. Now how can i swap two objects of class?
I wrote a swap function like this in my class:

```
void swap(class &A,class &B)
{
   class temp=*A;
   *A=*B;
   *B=temp;
}
```

can this function swap all of the elements?(even private one or no)

Comment: How are `A` and `B` related? Which copy constructors are provided?

Comment: A and B are two objects of a class and i want swap the value of them.

Comment: That syntax isn't valid C++.

Comment: "can this function swap all of the elements?" No, of course not. Code that doesn't compile doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

`class` cannot be used as a type name. You don't need to use `*` on references.

```
void swap(T& a, T& a)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

This only works if your assignment operator and copy constructor are correct for your class. Since these methods are class members it's doesn't matter whether you have private data members or not.

Comment: thanks john,can i use this swap function in a static function of this class?

Comment: @stella You don't need this function. It does the same as `std::swap`.

Comment: thanks juanchopanza, what is swap function library?

Comment: @stella See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap.